# ApplicationListener vs ServletContextListener

Tags: java, spring

What is the difference between ApplicationListener and ServletContextListener? When do you use them?

```
implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> 

implements ServletContextListener
```

Answer (score 1):

One allows you to monitor application-scoped events of your Spring application (e.g. [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html)) and the other allows you to monitor lifecycle events ([initialized/destroyed](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#method_summary)) of the ServletContext.  The former is Spring application related, the latter is container related.